# how to unable back in android using firebase auth android

Tags: android, kotlin

i had a problem when I'm trying to make logout button, it's success when i press the logout button but when i press back button, the screen move to previous activity, how to make to unable the back button without unable the onbackpressed function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);` whenever you start new activity on logout button click.

This will clear all activities from back stack , so when you press back button app will not open previous activity.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the application after `logout`, then call `finishAffinity()` in `onBackPressed()` method as

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    finishAffinity()
}
```

OR, If you want to navigate to other `activity` after `logout`, then

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    // Write your code here
    super.onBackPressed()
}
```

Comment: yes, but in my case i won't disable the back button.

Comment: Then use `sharedpreference` to check for login status, if the status is false, then `onBackPressed()` method move to other activity or call `finishAffinity()` to close the application

Answer (score 0):

i got maybe it's a best practice

```
startActivity(intentFor<LoginActivity>().newTask().clearTask())
```